# Unable to call props function in child component react

Tags: reactjs

I am passing in a function from a parent component to a child component using props. Something like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {

    someFunction = () => {}   

    render() {
       return(
          <Child propsFunction={this.someFunction} />
       )
     }
 }



 class Child extends Component {

    callFunction = () => {
        this.props.someFunction
    }

    render() {
        return(nothing here)
    }
 }

 export default nodeModule(Child)
```

I am using a node module that will automatically call the callfunction so I don't need to call it anywhere in the render. However when I run the code, I get:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

The error points to this.props.someFunction in the Child component.

Comment: `this.props.someFunction()` execute it please.

Comment: When I execute it it then says, it is not a function

Comment: What do you even mean by `node module that will automatically call the callfunction`. Why have you exported your class with HOC `nodeModule`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `this.props.someFunction` inside the Child component but it's named as `propsFunction` in Parent component.